# Node.js Typescript Express Error handling middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, error-handling, prisma

I'm trying to build an error middleware for error handling my backend routes, but for some reason it's not catching the errors, can someone help me with this?

App.ts

```
import { Middlewares } from "@middlewares/middlewares";
import authRoute from "@routes/authRoutes";
import registerRoute from "@routes/registerRoutes";
import userRoute from "@routes/userRoutes";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";

dotenv.config();

const middlewares = new Middlewares();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

app.get("/", (_req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello, world!" });
});

app.use("/user", userRoute);
app.use("/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/register", registerRoute);

app.use(middlewares.errorHandler);

export default app;
```

Error middleware

```
public errorHandler = (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (err instanceof DatabaseError) {
      return res.status(err.statusCode).json({ message: err.message });
    }
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong' });
  };
```

User model

```
public create = async (userData: userData) => {
    const user = await this._prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { email: userData.email },
    });      

    if (user) {
      throw new DatabaseError('User already exists');
    }

    try {
      const [user] = await this._prisma.$transaction([
        this._prisma.user.create({
          data: userData,
        }),
      ]);
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
          throw new DatabaseError(e.message);
        }
      }
  };
```

Route

```
import { RegisterController } from "@controllers/registerController";
import { Middlewares } from "@middlewares/middlewares";
import { UserModel } from "@models/userModel";
import { UserService } from "@services/userService";
import prisma from "@utils/prismaClient";
import { tryCatch } from "@utils/tryCatch";
import { Router } from "express";

const route = Router();

const userModel = new UserModel(prisma);
const userService = new UserService(userModel);
const registerController = new RegisterController(userService);
const middlewares = new Middlewares();

route.post("/", middlewares.upload, tryCatch(registerController.register));

export default route;
```

tryCatch wrapper

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

export const tryCatch =
  (
    controller: (
      req: Request,
      res: Response,
      next: NextFunction
    ) => Promise<void>
  ) =>
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      await controller(req, res, next);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
```

Basically, I'm testing if the error for duplicate user creation is working, and it won't catch the error and act like everything went ok, it is showing the error on the console but it's showing as if I created the user normally